# Flask tutorial : cannot execute .run.py. terminal doenst recognize shebang?

Tags: python, flask

I am following the tutorial here:

https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world

I have also create a

> app/view.py

```
from app import app

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
  return "Hello World!"
```

and

> app/**init**.py

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
from app import views
```

I am down to the last step and written the

> run.py

file as such:

```
#!flask/bin/python
from app import app
app.run(debug=True)
```

I am running it by evoking the `./run.py` command in terminal. getting the following error:

> ```
> from: can't read /var/mail/app
> ./run.py: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `debug=True'
> ./run.py: line 4: `app.run(debug=True)'
> ```

I am running a conda virtual environment.

All the answers I see online suggest adding the shebang but its already there. I will appreciate guidance on this.

Answer (score 0):

That's not a valid shebang - it has to be an *absolute* pathname, in other words the first character after the `#!` can only be a slash.

Comment: the shebang is copied verbatim from the tutorial. Does it have to do with the fact that its a conda environment?

Comment: Copied verbatim from WHAT?  A copied mistake is still a mistake.

Comment: Fair point. I have updated with a slash and got this error: -bash: ./run.py: /flask/bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Comment: Well, yeah - I wouldn't expect a `/flask` directory to exist.  `/usr/bin/python` is a much more likely pathname for your Python executable.

Comment: Thanks alot! it seemed to work but it is throwing another error. "no module named flask". This is odd as I have used conda --create flask to make the environment. Many thanks for righting wrong :)

Comment: It looks like there's a `python` inside a `flask` directory somewhere that you need to point to, rather than the systemwide `python`.  Sorry, I'm not at all familiar with conda.

Comment: if you have a special environment to run your flask app (like it could be with virtualenv), then don't use shebang but directly the executable of your env: ie. `flask/bin/python run.py`